# Returning Audio in Dialogflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialogflow-es

I'm using dialogflow and my current script returns the response of the agent in a textual format via: `content.queryResult.fulfillmentText;`
I want to also return the synthesised audio response, I'm using Dialogflow API.v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the settings in your Dialogflow agent, in the "Speech" tab, you can toggle-on the "Enable Automatic Text to Speech" option to always generate the audio for a conversation.

In addition, there's more settings that you can tune to control the Voice Configuration.

[image: Dialogflow Speech information]

You can also set this configuration in a per-request basis by using the [outputAudioConfig parameter in the DerectIntentRequest](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.DetectIntentRequest.html).

Finally, you can find the [audioOutput in the DetectIntentResponse](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.DetectIntentResponse.html#Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_DetectIntentResponse_OutputAudio).

Comment: Thanks, how would this look in a script?